# $\int_{\bf R}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}~dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\bf R}u(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}~dx$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, heat-equation

What is the sufficient condition such that this following equality holds :  $$\int_{\bf R}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}~dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\bf R}u(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}~dx$$

This question is about heat equation which is dealt with Fourier Transform . Any comment or advice will be appreciated . Thanks for considering my request .

Comment: Observe that the exponential does not depend on $t$. Then check whether you are in the framework of the "differentiation under the integral sign" theorem (c.f. : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). On a sidenote, are there no additional hypotheses on the growth of $u$ in space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that for each fixed $t$, the function $x\rightarrow u(x,t)$ is $L^{1}({\bf{R}})$.

Suppose further that for each fixed $x$, the function $t\rightarrow u(x,t)$ is $C^{1}({\bf{R}})$ and that for fixed $x$, the function $t\rightarrow\partial_{2}u(x,t)\leq\varphi(x)$ for a $\varphi\in L^{1}({\bf{R}})$.

Now for a fixed $t$, and for small $|h|>0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\bf{R}}\dfrac{1}{h}[u(x,t+h)-u(x,t)]e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx&=\int_{\bf{R}}\partial_{2}u(x,\eta_{x,h,t})e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx,
\end{align*} 
and we see that 
\begin{align*}
|\partial_{1}u(x,\eta_{x,h,t})|\leq\varphi(x),
\end{align*}
then by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\bf{R}}\dfrac{1}{h}[u(x,t+h)-u(x,t)]e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx\rightarrow\int_{\bf{R}}\partial_{2}u(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx,
\end{align*}
put it another way, 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{\bf{R}}u(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx=\int_{\bf{R}}\partial_{2}u(x,t)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx.
\end{align*}