# Are these conditions sufficient for this theorem to hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $F(s)=\int_a^b f(t,s)\,dt$ where $f(t,s)$ is a continuous complex function in the rectangle $$R=\{(t,s): a\leq t\leq b,\, c\leq s \leq d\}$$
>   If the partial derivative $f_s(t,s)$ exists and is continuous on $R$, then the derivative $F’(s)$ exists for every $s\in[c,d]$ and is given by 
>   $$F’(s)=\int_a^b f_s(t,s)\,dt.$$

Is continuity of $f(s,t)$ and $ f_s(s,t )$ the only condition required for this theorem to be true? I am familiar with differentiation under the integral sign for the real case (Lebesgue integration) in which other conditions (other then continuity) must be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t,s)=g(t,s)+ih(t,s)$ for real $g,h$, then $g,g_{s},h,h_{s}$ are continuous. 
Let $G(s)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}g(t,s)dt$, $H(s)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}h(t,s)dt$, then $F(s)=G(s)+iH(s)$ for real $G,H$.

Assume that we have the result for the real case, then $G'(s)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}g_{s}(t,s)dt$, $H'(s)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}h_{s}(t,s)dt$, then $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f_{s}(t,s)dt=\int_{a}^{b}[g_{s}(t,s)+ih_{s}(t,s)]dt=G'(s)+H'(s)$, then $F'(s)$ exists and the result follows.

Comment: Do you have any references for the real case?

Comment: I believe the real case has been proved many times in MSE, essentially just apply Mean Value Theorem and continuity of partial derivative to get the dominated integrable function for which Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem goes through.

Comment: You may look at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653953/int-bf-r-frac-partial-u-partial-tx-te-2-pi-ix-xidx-fracddt-i) to modify the proof of the case for real functions.